# Procedure not looping properly

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, cursors

I have several client databases on one server. They all have a prefix. Lets use "piggy_" as the prefix for the purposes of this.

I.e.

```
piggy_client_a
piggy_client_b
piggy_client_c
```

Below is the code of the three piggy databases and add a bunch of users. (For testing):

```
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS piggy_client_a;

CREATE TABLE piggy_client_a.user (
  id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  fullname VARCHAR(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  email VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO piggy_client_a.user (fullname, email) VALUES
("chris davis", "chris@something.com"),
("chris td", "chris@something.com"),
("bob sinclair", "bob@spectrum.net"),
("frank sidebottom", "frank@bighead.com");

CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS piggy_client_b;

CREATE TABLE piggy_client_b.user (
  id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  fullname VARCHAR(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  email VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO piggy_client_b.user (fullname, email) VALUES
("fanny adams", "chris@elsewhere.net"),
("colin furry", "colin@something.com"),
("chris grumps", "grumpy@htom.com"),
("tracey singer", "trace@email.com");

CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS piggy_client_c;

CREATE TABLE piggy_client_c.user (
  id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  fullname VARCHAR(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  email VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO piggy_client_c.user (fullname, email)VALUES
("mary qos", "mary@comms.com"),
("curtis jackson", "curtis@something.com"),
("christine motor", "chrissy@live.net"),
("tom peters", "tom@peters.org");
```

Within each piggy database is the same schema. One of those tables is `user` and I want to find any of these databases where the user exists.

I have written a stored procedure and it works, on the whole. However it only ever processes the first piggy database. I have double checked and if I add a particular user into the `piggy_client_c` database, it is not returned.

Here is my code:

```sql
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `find_user`$$

CREATE PROCEDURE `find_user`(IN partial_name VARCHAR(20))
BEGIN

    DECLARE database_name VARCHAR(128) DEFAULT '';
    DECLARE non_found INTEGER DEFAULT 0;

    DECLARE database_list 
        CURSOR FOR 
            SELECT SCHEMA_NAME FROM information_schema.SCHEMATA 
            WHERE SCHEMA_NAME LIKE `piggy_client_%` 
            ORDER BY SCHEMA_NAME ASC;

    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET non_found = 1;

    OPEN database_list;

    check_table: LOOP

        FETCH database_list INTO database_name;

        IF non_found = 1 THEN 
            LEAVE check_table;
        END IF;

        SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT "',database_name,'" AS db_name, fullname,email FROM ',database_name,'.user WHERE trim(fullname) like "%',partial_name,'%"');

        PREPARE db_statement FROM @sql;
        EXECUTE db_statement;
        DEALLOCATE PREPARE db_statement;

    END LOOP check_table;

    CLOSE database_list;

END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

I cannot see anything that would cause the function to exit, or not loop through the cursor, but I am fairly new to this.

Or, if I could "step" through the code, that would be useful, or output debug info.

TIA, Chris

Comment: Perhaps you could print the value of `@sql` and try executing it manually to see if it is valid.

Comment: It is valid, it returns rows if I use a name that is in the first `piggy` database, just not any subsequent databases. And I checked the cursor definition returns multiple databases too

Comment: I've added an SQL to recreate the test schemas/tables

Comment: Sorry, yes there is a user in each database starting with "chris". I added an SQL yesterday to recreate the table(s) - find_user("chris") only returns the one from the first database

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code there is an error in:

```
SELECT SCHEMA_NAME FROM information_schema.SCHEMATA 
WHERE SCHEMA_NAME LIKE `piggy_client_%` 
ORDER BY SCHEMA_NAME ASC;
```

Replace backticks with string delimiter as in:

```
SELECT SCHEMA_NAME FROM information_schema.SCHEMATA 
WHERE SCHEMA_NAME LIKE 'piggy_client_%' 
ORDER BY SCHEMA_NAME ASC;
```

I created a [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/a7kedUeFmCu4tWLFRoxMJA/3)

You also mis-use double quotes as string delimiters. You insert statement should look like:

```
('fanny adams', 'chris@elsewhere.net'),
```

But apparently that works, so I have not fixed that.

Comment: FWIW, dbfiddle.uk is a different fiddle site that does preserve DBMS brand and version.

Comment: Quite right, the back ticks in the cursor were the issue. However, it appears SequelPro doesn't run the procedure correctly. I ran it in the console and it worked fine. So thats great, thank you

Comment: @BillKarwin, thats the site I normally use, but it did not understand the DELIMITER part